# Limitation in counting down loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following simple Excel spreadsheet:

```
      A           B              C
1                 10
2               =B1+A2
3             =SUMME(B1:B2)
4
```

In cell A2 counting down values are inserted by the following macro:

```
Sub test ()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1
Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3") > 0
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

This all works fine so far. However, now I want to limit the loop in the macro. So it should only countdown numbers in cell A2 until it reaches number 0. It should never go below 0.

Do you have any idea how I can insert such a "limit" in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It should never go below 0.

Before writing the value, check if it is `<0` and simply exit the `Do` loop.

Is this what you want?

```
Do Until Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3") > 0
    If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1 < 0 Then Exit Do
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1
Loop
```

Comment: Hi Siddharth, I tried your code but it exits the loop although the value in cell A2 is > 0.

Comment: It will not.  Can you make sure that the condition `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B3") > 0` is not met? Step through the code to check it ;)

Comment: Just change the following line in Sid's code:                                              `If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1 <= 0 Then Exit Do`                           Withe this: `If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2").Value - 1 < 0 Then Exit Do`

Comment: @Jeremy: Thanks. I have amended that :)